# RoR: Semantic-ui and check box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I'm using *semantic-ui-sass* and I'm not able to use the check box in rails.

That's working:

```
<div>
 <%= f.label :remember_me, "Angemeldet bleiben?" %>
 <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
</div>
```

This is working as well:

```
<div class="ui checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="example">
  <label>Make my profile visible</label>
</div>
```

But this is NOT:

```
<div class="ui checkbox">
  <%= f.label :remember_me, "Angemeldet bleiben?" %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution; all I have to do is to change the order of

> f.check_box and f.label

This one is working:

```
  <div class="ui checkbox">
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
    <%= f.label :remember_me, "Angemeldet bleiben?" %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails form automaticaly creates his own divs and classes so you can't mix both. You can do this though:

```
<%= f.label :remember_me, "Angemeldet bleiben?" %>
<%= f.check_box :remember_me, :class => "ui checkbox" %>
```

Sorry mistyped